# How to Zeppelin Notebook Using Scala 2.12

Tags: scala, apache-zeppelin

I have been using Jupyter notebook with Almond for the Scala kernel, but I ran into nasty issues when using it with Apache Spark, so I decided to try Zeppelin but ran into fundamental issue. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

[image: Zeppe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about scala version, this is just due to you have already had this note in your notebooks